# Item in review queue with "Skip" button only

Tags: bug, review

I'm reviewing suggested edits on serverfault, and I have a problem with this item :

https://serverfault.com/review/suggested-edits/441377

I'm only able to select "Skip", no Approve, Reject,... buttons is this a bug ?

Screenshot of the issue : [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the question was [locked](https://serverfault.com/posts/60737/timeline#history_ef5cf4e6-6d1d-4658-948b-11f318b1c255) a few days ago so suggested edits can't be applied to it.

Locking should have cancelled any pending edits, that it did not is a bug but a rare one as locking of posts is uncommon.